# Execute jquery function in file that is loaded using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 PHP file, index.php , pro.php and js.js .
this is index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tracking HTML File</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>
<div id="bbb"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is pro.php file:

```
<div id="ccc">ccc</div>
<div id="zzz"></div>
```

this is js.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aaa').click(function() {
        $('#bbb').load('pro.php');
    })
    $('#ccc').click(function() {
        $('#zzz').load('ather_file.php');
    })
})
```

what i want is when i click on ccc, the file with name ather_file.php must be loaded to zzz div, but i don't know how to do something like that, i include the js files in both files, but i didn't success .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is working example

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#aaa').click(function () {
                $('#bbb').load('pro.html', null, function () {
                    $('#ccc').click(function () {
                        $('#zzz').load('ather_file.html');
                    })
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="aaa">aaa</div>
    <div id="bbb"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

main problem that you tried to assign click to 'ccc' when it wasn't in DOM yet

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are adding the elements after the dom is ready, you should change:

```
$('#ccc').click(function() {})
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ccc', function() {})
```

this will delegate events on the fly, even after dom ready. And should allow you to only have the js file on the top level

Comment: do you have an example/demo i can take a look at?

Comment: i will try to make one, just a minute .

Comment: thanks for your help ,the other answer that's giving is working .

Comment: are you adding extra stuff to it? both of our answers should function about the same.

Comment: here is [mine](http://thedanktank.com/test2.html) and here is [Alex's](http://thedanktank.com/test.html). It appears that neither of them fully work.